# Giving a wrong count for a data read from a file

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I was trying reading and writing some data from a file and counting very simple features from the written data such as number of spaces etc. using the split() method. Here is what I tried.

```
    File file=new File("G:\\AAA.txt");

    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file);

    fw.write("AAAAAAAA");

    fw.flush();
    fw.close();

    FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);

    String spaces="\\s";

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

    String data=br.readLine();
    System.out.println(data);

    String[] tokenize=data.split(spaces);
    System.out.println(tokenize.length);
```

My problem is if there are no spaces I am getting the answer as 1 though it must be 0. when I was given 1 space it prints as 2. The answer is always larger than 1 from the given spaces.

Could someone please explain me the reason for not getting the exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) of String.split

> > If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

So with no spaces, the original string will be returned, thus the length of 1.

If you have one space, say "AAA AAA", the array will have two elements "AAA" and "AAA". So the length will always be one greater than the number of tokens.

Comment: Hello Jeff thanks for replying. K I got what you said. But if I have "AAA  AAA" with two spaces in between how do I get the answer as 3? It counts the number of spaces right? So is it a good method to count features of a large string? To get the exact answer do I need always to subtract 1 from the answer o.O..?

Comment: `"AAA  AAA".split("\\s")` will return an array of length 3. http://ideone.com/Az8EXX

Comment: Try Apache's countMatches https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

**Why one if no space**

If there is no string matched in `split(#regex)` , it will return input string into array of string.

**Why always more than one if Space**

It will split string by space , so first and second half will be there in array. So Length is greater than one.

**Finding Count of Space**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("AA   A");

int count = 0;
while (matcher.find())
    count++;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Siva. Is it a good method to count number of spaces in a string? Could you please explain me how "AA   A" with three spaces give me answer as 4? To get the exact number of spaces do I need to subtract 1 from the answer I get?

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
     
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("AA   A");
     
     int count = 0;
     while (matcher.find())
         count++; You can use like that